# How to add up the score in a simple game and have the correct and wrong answer

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a simple game. Basically the player has to select the correct maths equation which equals to the price. There are three random prices which will appear when the game starts, and the player will have to select the button beside the correct maths equation. What I am struggling on is adding up the score and having the CORRECT or FALSE banner pop up when the button is selected. I have tried a few different things but nothing seems to be working unless there is a small bit of javascript missing.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<title>How much are the tickets?</title>

<!-- These are the links for The script and CSS-->
<script src="scripting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css"/>
</head>

 <!--This is the body with the default background I chose-->   
<body onload="disablebuttons()" background="background3.gif">


 <!--The game and the timer will not begin until the user clicks the button-->  
<div><input type = "button" value = "Begin the Game" onClick = "start();" id="button3"></div>


<!--The Winner/Loser block that displays if you win/lose-->
  <div id="blockparty"></div>

<!--This is the ticketman-->  

<div id = "TM">
<img src="tm.gif"> </img>
</div>


 <!--This is the speech bubble where the price of the ticket will appear when the game begins-->
<div id = "speechbubble">
<img src = "bubble1.gif" id="speechbubble1">
</div>

<!--These are the tickets where the maths equation will be-->

<div id = "ticket1">
<img src = "ticket1.gif" id="equation1">
</div>


<div id = "ticket2">
<img src = "ticket2.gif" id="equation2">
</div>


<div id = "ticket3">
<img src = "ticket3.gif" id="equation3">
</div>

<!--These are the tickets where the maths equation will be-->

<div><input type = "button" value = "1" onClick = "one();" id="tktbtn1"></div>

<div><input type = "button" value = "2" onClick = "two();" id="tktbtn2"></div>

<div><input type = "button" value = "3" onClick = "three();" id="tktbtn3"></div>


<!--This is the score, I set it to 0 so it displays when the page loads, it's a placeholder until the draw button is hit, the draw function is then targeted and it writes the score. It will either add 5 or take away 10 depending on if the player wins or loses.-->
<div id="scored">0</div>

<!--This is the reset score button. I made it a p tag and in my css I made it so that when you hover over it the cursor will appear as a pointer-->

<p id="resetscore" onclick="resetscore();"><u>Reset</u></p>


<!--The Winner/Loser block that displays if you win/lose-->
  <div id="blockparty"></div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Here is my javascript - I have included descriptions of what I was trying to do within the javascript.

```
/*These are the vars that I used in my project. 

User = The Player
Comp = The Computer
Chosen = The ticket selected
Score = Used to add/minus the score
*/


var user;
var comp;
var chosen;
var score = 0;

//* This function disables the buttons at the beginning*/

function disablebuttons(){
    document.getElementById("tktbtn1").disabled= true;
    document.getElementById("tktbtn2").disabled= true;
    document.getElementById("tktbtn3").disabled= true;
    document.getElementById("resetscore").disabled= true;

}

/* This is my start button function, it calls on the computer once the start button is selected*/

function start(){  
        comp = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;   
        document.getElementById('speechbubble1').src = 'bubble/price' + comp + '.gif';
        document.getElementById("tktbtn1").disabled= false;
        document.getElementById("tktbtn2").disabled= false;
        document.getElementById("tktbtn3").disabled= false;
        document.getElementById("resetscore").disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('equation1').src = 'tickets/maths1.gif';
        document.getElementById('equation2').src = 'tickets/maths2.gif';
        document.getElementById('equation3').src = 'tickets/maths3.gif';
}


/* This function puts everything back to normal 5 seconds after the player selected their answer*/
function reset(){

    document.getElementById('blockparty').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('speechbubble1').src = "bubble/price" + comp + '.gif';
    document.getElementById("tktbtn1").disabled= true;
    document.getElementById("tktbtn2").disabled= true;
    document.getElementById("tktbtn3").disabled= true;
    document.getElementById("resetscore").disabled= true;
    document.getElementById('equation1').src = 'tickets/maths1.gif';
    document.getElementById('equation2').src = 'tickets/maths2.gif';
    document.getElementById('equation3').src = 'tickets/maths3.gif';

}

/*
  This add either 5 or 0 to the score depending on the result,
  It displays a block saying: Correct/False
```

and it also sets a timeout after 5 seconds, that then puts everything back to    normal as displayed above*/

```
function begin(){
    user = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;   
    document.getElementById('player').src = 'bubble/price' +user+ '.gif';
    document.getElementById('blockparty').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("tktbtn1").disabled= true;
    document.getElementById("tktbtn2").disabled= true;
    document.getElementById("tktbtn3").disabled= true;
    document.getElementById("resetscore").disabled= true;
    document.getElementById('equation1').src = 'tickets/maths1.gif';
    document.getElementById('equation2').src = 'tickets/maths2.gif';
    document.getElementById('equation3').src = 'tickets/maths3.gif'; }

if (chosen == "correct1;" && "tktbtn1" + "price1"){
    document.getElementById('blockparty').innerHTML= "CORRECT!";
    document.getElementById("blockparty").style.backgroundColor="green";
    document.getElementById("scored").innerHTML = score = score + 5;}

else if (chosen == "false1;" && "tktbtn3" + "price1"){
    document.getElementById('blockparty').innerHTML= "FALSE!";
    document.getElementById("blockparty").style.backgroundColor="red";
    document.getElementById("scored").innerHTML = score = score + 0;}

else if (chosen == "false2;" && "tktbtn2" + "price1"){
    document.getElementById('blockparty').innerHTML= "FALSE!";
    document.getElementById("blockparty").style.backgroundColor="red";
    document.getElementById("scored").innerHTML = score = score + 0;}

else if (chosen == "correct2;" && "tktbtn2" + "price2"){
    document.getElementById('blockparty').innerHTML= "CORRECT!";
    document.getElementById("blockparty").style.backgroundColor="green";
    document.getElementById("scored").innerHTML = score = score + 5;}

else if (chosen == "false3;" && "tktbtn3" + "price2"){
    document.getElementById('blockparty').innerHTML= "FALSE!";
    document.getElementById("blockparty").style.backgroundColor="red";
    document.getElementById("scored").innerHTML = score = score + 0;}

else if (chosen == "false4;" && "tktbtn1" + "price2"){
    document.getElementById('blockparty').innerHTML= "FALSE!";
    document.getElementById("blockparty").style.backgroundColor="red";
    document.getElementById("scored").innerHTML = score = score + 0;}

else if (chosen == "correct3;" && "tktbtn3" + "price3"){
    document.getElementById('blockparty').innerHTML= "CORRECT!";
    document.getElementById("blockparty").style.backgroundColor="green";
    document.getElementById("scored").innerHTML = score = score + 5;}

else if (chosen == "false5;" && "tktbtn1" + "price3"){
    document.getElementById('blockparty').innerHTML= "FALSE!";
    document.getElementById("blockparty").style.backgroundColor="red";
    document.getElementById("scored").innerHTML = score = score + 0;}

else if (chosen == "false6;" && "tktbtn2" + "price3"){
    document.getElementById('blockparty').innerHTML= "FALSE!";
    document.getElementById("blockparty").style.backgroundColor="red";
    document.getElementById("scored").innerHTML = score = score + 0;}

else {
    document.getElementById("blockparty").innerHTML= "Loser!";
    document.getElementById("blockparty").style.backgroundColor="red";
    document.getElementById("scored").innerHTML = score = score + -10;}
    setTimeout('reset()', 5000);
}


/*This sets the score back to 0 once the reset p tag is clicked. This prevents the score from adding up once the game is reset.*/
function resetscore(){
document.getElementById("scored").innerHTML = score = score = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why dont u put your html too so we get a better understanding about what youre tryin to do here?

Comment: just added the html there!

Comment: What is your intention by `.innerHTML = score = score + 0` ?

Comment: its meant to be .innerHTML  = score + 0

Comment: so that when it is reset, the score will go back to 0

Comment: I dont think this html code you gave is complete. All the elements that you refered by their ids are missing. `tktbtn1, tktbtn2, ...`

Comment: `score -= score` would decrement the value to 0. You could use other [assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Subtraction_assignment_2) for the operations in the other conditions as well.
Also you're querying the DOM for the same elements far too many times, you'd be better of storing them in vars, for example:
`var blockpartyEl = document.getElementById('blockparty');`

Comment: Since the same operation with different values are being repeated in the most of your conditions you could encapsulate them in a function, then just pass in the relevant values as arguments:

`function setResult(truthy, color, newPoints){
 blockpartyEl.innerHTML = truthy;
 blockpartyEl.style.backgroundColor = color;
 scoredEl.innerHTML = score += newPoints;
}`

Comment: i changed the html again, i pasted in the wrong one sorry

Comment: ok i will try do what ye say, getting quiet confused tho

Comment: Where does the initial assignment to the variable `chosen` take place? Also with the operand on the right-hand side of the [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_(.26.26)) operators in your conditionals you're simply adding/concatenating strings.. So the value will always be `true`. What purpose does this serve?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function that doesn't exist. Did you just not include them? Function 'one', 'two', and 'three'. Example:

```
<div><input type = "button" value = "1" onClick = "one();" id="tktbtn1"></div>
```

Also, you never actually call the 'begin' function. And even if you did, it looks like there is a curly bracket closing it before the conditional statements begin.